# Setting element height relative to available space

Tags: wpf, xaml

My grid currently has the following rows defined:

```
<RowDefinition Height="50" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

Unfortunately the data I'm loading into this, even with a `ScrollViewer` makes the window too "tall" and I lose some of it off the bottom of my screen.

To fix this, I was thinking of doing something like `Height="* - x"` where x is the amount of pixels I'd like to subtract from whatever value `*` would be.

Unfortunately this isn't valid markup so how would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `MaxHeight`?

Comment: Create another RowDefinition with a Height of X or add X to the height of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you are asking for:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Button" />

    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="2000">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Grid.Row=0" />

            <Rectangle Fill="Crimson"  Grid.Row="1" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

[image: Scroll at top]

[image: Scroll at bottom]

Comment: What are the `DockPanel` and `Button` for? Do they make any difference?

Comment: The Button is just there to show that it is never hidden independently the height of the scrollviewer.

The Dockpanel is there to make the Scrollviewer fill all the available space (Not sure if Scrollviewer does already this for its own).